# How can I write a loop for this program so it returns to top every time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code i am working with. It is to make a stepper motor spin but after every time it goes through the code it stops altogether. How can I just make the code begin over again?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(16, 500)


def SpinMotor(direction, num_steps):
    GPIO.output(18, direction)
    while num_steps > 0:
        p.start(1)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        num_steps -= 1
    p.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    return True

direction_input = raw_input('Please enter O or C for Open or Close')
num_steps = input('Please enter the number of steps:')
if direction_input == 'O':
    SpinMotor(True, num_steps)

else:
    SpinMotor(False, num_steps)
```

Comment: `while True:` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop like this:

```
while True:
    direction_input = raw_input('Please enter O or C for Open or Close. Q to quit.')
    if direction_input == 'Q':
        break
    num_steps = input('Please enter the number of steps:')
    if direction_input == 'O':
        SpinMotor(True, num_steps)

    else:
        SpinMotor(False, num_steps)
```